# Android app: "NEVERMIND" button in dialog is confusing, should say "Cancel" instead

Tags: bug, android-app

When I clicked the little down  arrow in order to discard the comment I was writing, I was a little surprised (and baffled for a moment), when it showed me the following dialog:

> [image]

Shouldn't that cancel button which for some reason says "Nevermind", say, well, "Cancel" instead ?

In all the other dialogs, it does say "Cancel", just not in this one for some reason.

Comment: The latest update just made it worse, having now the buttons near each other and UPPER CASE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the screenshot, I had added one, but but my internet dropped just before I realized that it wasn't there for some reason. That was irritating.. FYI, it's not in uppercase for me (even though I'm on the latest beta version), so I guess it's android version related ? This is what it looks like for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HzVsJ.jpg .

Comment: This looks like the one in the older post (8 months ago) so likely you still didn't update the app, I updated it yesterday. (not beta, from Google Play)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The uppercase and the position is the default style for Material design, unfortunately...

Comment: And in the SE app, it's only used on devices where material is the default theme, that is android 5+. I got the update from Google Play yesterday, and it still looks the same. I'm on 4.4, so it follows whatever the default theme for your device is, @Sha

Comment: Oh, so android itself became UGLY and SHOUTING. Oh well, guess nothing is perfect. Still amazing app can't decide to write in small case or where each button will be, though.